# How to set an alias on a Model::query() in Phalcon Framework

Tags: mysql, join, model, alias, phalcon

How to set an SQL alias for a Phalcon Model. A method **alias()** does not exist.

A sample of what i need:

```
$modelA = ModelA::query()
          ->alias('q')
          ->columns(['q.*','concat(q.id,r.id)) 
          ->join('ModelB', 'q.id = r.model_a_id', 'r', 'LEFT');
```

How can I create **q** alias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model `query` returns `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria`. There is not method to set `alias`.
You can get what are you trying with `modelManager` as-

```
    $modelA = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
        ->addFrom('ModelA', 'q')
        ->join('ModelB', 'a.id = r.model_a_id', 'r')
        ->columns(['q.*','concat(q.id,r.id))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```